# control SQL Server database stop/start

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to know how many different ways or different reasons why database (not instance, not server, but database) is stopped/started. I am analyzing SQL Server logs.

Currently as far as I know, two possible ways/reasons are -- taking database offline/online and stop/start instance/server.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Can you tell us what prompted you to ask for database going on/off? We could give you better answers if we know what troubles you... hold on, hold on.. i just meant in SQL Server terms :D

Comment: Thanks Raj! I find in SQL Server log, there is items like database XXX start and stop, and I want to find reasons why database start/stop because I have never explicitly start/stop SQL Server instances. Any ideas what are the possible ways we could start/stop database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server / service is restarted unexpectedly, a database can go into recovery mode and will be unaccessible for the duration.

I have also seen scenarios where a database is rolling back/forward transactions right after my server was restarted.

Other than SQL Server logs, a very good place to look is in the Windows Event Logs on the server.

**EDIT based on comments:**

I think that the AUTO CLOSE property of your database(s) is set to true. These databases are set to close after the last user exits.  Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx.

You can turn this off by issuing this command

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

Comment: " a database can go into recovery mode and will be unaccessible for the duration." -- is this scenario related to my question about database start/stop? My confusion is you are talking about "recovery mode", but I am talking about start/stop database, are we talking about the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: "Other than SQL Server logs, a very good place to look is in the Windows Event Logs on the server." -- why? Could you show me a sample why using event log is more accurate then SQL Server log?

Comment: Simply because the windows event log will give you information about anything else happening on the server, not just within SQL Server, so you can link events temporally.

Comment: Thanks Raj, besides setting auto_close, explicitly detach/attach, taking offline/online, stop instance, any other ways do you think of which cause a specific database stop/start?

Comment: Those are the only ones I know of.

Answer (score 2):

A database is never started or stopped. It's either online or offline, but it's not a service that's running. Rather, it's a file (or collection of files) on the hard disk. The only thing that gets stopped or started is the windows service.

A database can be taken offline with a detach or you can use `alter database mydb set offline` if you felt like it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The reason why I call database start/stop is because I find in SQL Server logs, there are items like database XXX start/stop. My confusion is I did not explicitly call offline statement or using SSMS to take database offline, why there is logs in database server mentions database start/stop? Any possible reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the Auto_Close option for the databases in question is set to OFF.  If a database is set for AUTO_CLOSE ON then it will close when all the connections to it close.

See the BOL topic for ALTER DATABASE for further information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135094.aspx